# import command is not working in imagemagick

Tags: linux, imagemagick, xvfb

I Have installed firefox and Xvfb on remote linux. and i am running the Xvfb and firefox this way,

```
Xvfb :99
DISPLAY=:99 firefox http://www.google.com &
DISPLAY=:99 import -window root googledotcom.png
```

but the last command is not working nothing is happening and i have to manually suspend the last command !
yesterday it was working as i have to write a shell script for all i uninstalled Xvfb firefox imagemagick and installed it again since then it is not taking screenshot. initially it was taking.

any help ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to add a delay such that firefox can boot & load the URL.

```
export DISPLAY=:99
Xvfb :99 & firefox -browser
firefox -url http://www.google.com & sleep 5 && import -display $DISPLAY -window root googledotcom.png
```

[image: capture remote firefox in Xvfb with ImageMagick]

Comment: where the screen shot will be stored ?

Comment: Wherever you want it. The last argument in the `import` utility will be the destination path.

Comment: ok ! @emcconville can you help me with this question ?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37428948/running-xvfb-in-background-on-remote-linux/37429660#37429660