# running Xvfb in background on remote linux

Tags: linux, shell, xvfb

i am facing issues with Xvfb on remote linux.  when i run the command

```
Xvfb :99 &
```

I get this messages on the command line
    `Initializing built-in extension Generic Event Extension
Initializing built-in extension SHAPE
Initializing built-in extension MIT-SHM
Initializing built-in extension XInputExtension
Initializing built-in extension XTEST
Initializing built-in extension BIG-REQUESTS
Initializing built-in extension SYNC
Initializing built-in extension XKEYBOARD
Initializing built-in extension XC-MISC
Initializing built-in extension SECURITY
Initializing built-in extension XINERAMA
Initializing built-in extension XFIXES
Initializing built-in extension RENDER
Initializing built-in extension RANDR
Initializing built-in extension COMPOSITE
Initializing built-in extension DAMAGE
Initializing built-in extension MIT-SCREEN-SAVER
Initializing built-in extension DOUBLE-BUFFER
Initializing built-in extension RECORD
Initializing built-in extension DPMS
Initializing built-in extension Present
Initializing built-in extension X-Resource
Initializing built-in extension XVideo
Initializing built-in extension XVideo-MotionCompensation
Initializing built-in extension SELinux
Initializing built-in extension GLX`

and i have to suspend it using ctrl+c still it will be running in the background, i am writing a shell script to automate it but this command `Xvfb :99 &` is not running in the background ! any help regarding this ?

my shell script :

```
system("sudo yum -y install Xvfb");
system("sudo yum -y install firefox");
system("sudo yum -y install ImageMagick");
system("Xvfb :99 &");
system("export DISPLAY=:99");
```

Comment: I don't believe you would want to shell script this, but create a system service to manage Xvfb. Googling `Xvfb daemon` will give you plenty of examples & techniques.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

instead of & try to use below: 
issue ctrl+z command after entering Xvfb :99 
then enter bg to send the process to run in background and following would keep on running in background. 
EDIT: Below should also help:

```
nohup Xvfb :99 > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

or simply `nohup Xvfb :99 &`

Comment: oh..you wish to run this inside a script..then instead of issuing ctrl+z to xvfb..issue that to the script itself..so that script runs behind the scenes

Comment: So once you've issued ./script.sh then immediately press ctrl+z which should stop the process temporarily and then on the prompt type bg

Comment: would u consider accepting this as answer then..so that others looking for such query might find an easy solution

Comment: Sorry mate ! forgot earlier !

Comment: I wish there was a CLI flag instead. Having to wait in my script after a `&` is messy